# In a simple MVC Pattern, what component is responsible for originating (sending) data change events? What component receives them?

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns

Example: Assume we have an application with two windows of some sort, open with two different presentations (views) of the same data. The first view (or both views) provides the ability to modify the underling data (model). Presumably then, when a data (model) change is made, an event is fired which triggers the second view (and even possibly the first) that its model has changed and it needs to refresh itself. My questions:

1) What component fires the data change event? I presume that the model must fire the event because it certainly knows of data change events.

2) What component is listening to the model change events? Would it be the controller or the views?

3) Or am I taking too low a perspective on this and the MVC pattern does not prescribe such an event architecture?

Comment: in traditional MVC the view is an observer, meaning it's subscribed to particular objects in the model layer. the model, when updating, notifies its subscribers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, the model fires the events.
2. The views.
3. In its original form, MVC prescribes just such an event architecture. But note that MVC is much older than the Internet. The layered client/server architectures we commonly see today (sometimes called WebMVC) are something else.

See: [In MVC pattern, can the Model interact / modify the View?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53703012/1371329) for a slightly longer answer.

See: [Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html#ModelViewController) for a much longer answer.