# What is MVC in the context of backend?

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, backend

MVC in the frontend makes perfect sense. But why do we need MVC in the backend as well? Where is the "view" in this case given backend doesn't provide anything visual.

Comment: Who said we need MVC in the backend as well?

Comment: [MVC was invented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53712880/1371329) for desktop applications (backend). Frankly, I'm confused how it makes any sense in the front-end.

Comment: @jaco0646 backend for desktop application? How come desktop application needs a backend assuming it doesn't talk to backend.

Comment: Sounds like we're drawing the line between front and back in different places. In original MVC there is actually neither. Desktop apps don't use client/server architecture, so I suppose they are both front and back. My point was that MVC makes no sense in the context of client/server architecture. It makes no sense in the context of web applications. It makes no sense in the context of the Internet. MVC is a push architecture; but client/server is a pull architecture. It was so popular on the desktop that developers named whatever they did on the Web MVC anyway.

Comment: Desktop apps don't use client/server architecture? I disagree. You're saying every desktop app is standalone and doesn't save data. To me backend is the database (or maybe an application server). In summary none of this makes any sense to me :)

Comment: @jaco0646 Could you please tell me, what you mean by _"MVC is a push architecture; but client/server is a pull architecture."_? Thanks.

Comment: @dakis, see my comment to aridlehoover.

Comment: backend frameworks like Rails use MVC. so, it does make sense.

Answer (score 2):

MVC is a design pattern that promotes separation of concern where three participating concerns are
•

- The **Model** a data structure which holds business data and is
  transferred from one layer to the other.
- The **View** which is responsible to show the data present in the
  application or think of it as a data structure (*complete decoupled
  from the  model*) solely used for presentation purpose (not necessary a
  presentation output itself) e.g. view template in below diagram
- The **Controller** act as a mediator and is responsible to accept a
  request from a user, modify a model (if required) and convert it into
  the view.

MVC as a pattern can exist completely on the backend or completely on frontend or in its common form of backend and frontend combined.

One has to think relatively and see how to keep all these three concerns sperate for better application design.

The *whole idea behind MVC pattern* is a very clear separation between domain objects which represents real-world entities and the presentation layer data structure. Domain objects should be completely independent and should work without a View (data representation) as well. Or other way to think of it is, in MVC context views are isolated from the model. It allows to use the same model with different views.

*Spring MVC* is a good example of a backend MVC framework.

Below diagram depicts how all the three components exist on the server side only (inside the application container). *Taken from [official blog](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet) only.*

[image]

Comment: I hope you don't mind my MVC-opinion: (#) The model is a layer (not a data structure), containing various components responsible with the whole business logic in terms of business behavior (in the first place) and data. (#) Controller doesn't act as mediator, but only as... model updater. (#) The view itself communicates with the model, pulling and displaying necessary data from it. Controller should not pull data from model and push it to the view. (#) The whole idea behind MVC pattern is to separate business logic from UI logic (input & output both). Domain objects are just part of model.

Answer (score 1):

MVC is about separating concerns in applications that accept user input, perform business logic, and render output. It does not say where that logic resides. Nor does it specify that all the logic must live in a single process.

A fairly traditional use of MVC is with a spreadsheet. Let's look at both a single process application and a multi-process application to see how they might implement this simple spreadsheet:

```
     A     B       C
   ----- ----- ---------
1 |  1     2    =A1+B1
```

Let's say the user enters the number `4` into cell `A1`. What happens?

SINGLE PROCESS APPLICATION (e.g. Microsoft Excel): The user input is handled by the view logic, up until the user leaves the cell. Once that happens, the controller receives a message to update the model with the new value. The model accepts the new value, but also runs some business logic to update the values of other cells affected by the change. Once complete, the model notifies the view that its state has changed, and the view renders the new state. That notification can happen via pub/sub as @jaco0646 suggests, but it could also be handled with a callback.

MULTI-PROCESS APPLICATION (e.g. Google Sheets): The user input is handled by the view logic (in the client), up until the user leaves the cell. Once that happens, the controller (on the server) receives a message (via HTTP, or a socket) to update the model (also on the server) with the new value. The model accepts the new value, but also runs some business logic to update the values of other cells affected by the change. Once complete, the model notifies the view that its state has changed, and the view renders the new state (in the client). That notification can happen via the controller's HTTP response, or via a socket.

In other words, the MVC pattern is applicable to both scenarios.

Furthermore, it is also perfectly valid to treat the client and the server as two entirely separate applications, both of which might implement MVC. In this scenario, both the client's model, and the server's view are less traditional. The client's model is likely making AJAX requests to the server, as opposed to running complex business logic itself or persisting the data locally. And, the server's view is likely a serializer that produces some form of structured output that the client understands, like JSON, XML, or even a CSV.

MVC is a perfectly valid pattern anytime an application needs to accept user input, perform some business logic, and render some output -- regardless of whether that application lives on one or more processes -- and regardless of whether the view is something a human will consume.

Comment: I agree this is what the definition of MVC has evolved into. I'm less certain this is how it started out. The GoF design patterns book states, "_MVC decouples views and models by establishing a subscribe/notify protocol between them ._" That's it. Full stop. I see no room there for anything beyond a single-process application. That was in the context of Smalltalk-80; but regardless of era, an HTTP response is in no way a notification. A notification is a push; a response is a pull. A push architecture enables a model to (directly) update multiple views for a single data change.