# How and why can the Observer Pattern implement the MVC Architectural Style?

Tags: java, design-patterns, uml, observer-pattern

I would like to understand better how and why the observer pattern can be used to implement an MVC architecture. Can you explain how this could work, if possible with an example, and specify for each component its role?

Comment: You might want to ask that question on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53703012/in-mvc-pattern-can-the-model-interact-modify-the-view

Answer (score 1):

You'll find a detailed answer in [*Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns). In one of the introductory chapter they decompose MVC into a combination of several of their design patterns.

In [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), you have:

- A model, with the domain objects
- One controler, that takes care of the user input`
- One or several views, that show data of the model to the user.

A view may query the model, but a model may also inform views that some change took place.  This is typically implemented with the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern):

- the model is the observed subject
- the view is an observer that subscribes to the model
- when the model changes,  it notifies the view that a change took place.  The view can then query for changed data and refresh what's shown to the user.

If you want to dive deeper,  you may be interested in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZOmFr7KnUyU). The instructor provides a link to some course material, if you prefer to read than to look.

Comment: @Bruno thanks for your remark.  I thought that it could be a right place here, in view of the UML tag.  I've slightly reworded the question and voted for reopening it, so that  other relevant answers can be provided. Looking however at the more conceptual aspects of this question, I wonder if it would not indeed be better moved to SE, as someone suggested in the comments.

Comment: I also voted to reopen, I proposed to reopen to not have that question removed because closed. Concerning the 'best' place between here and SE frankly I don't know